# How to lock an object to certain datatype

Tags: java

I've got this practice problem in a first year programming course. I need to output "X Y Z" from the below code **without** modifying the sout line. The issue is that this outputs the numeric values for the characters X, Y, and Z (88, 89, and 90) instead of the characters themselves. Is there anyway you can lock objects as characters so they cannot be cast to integers?

```
public class LectureFour {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       
      char letter = 'X';
      char i;
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         System.out.print(letter + i + " ");

      }
   }
}
```

What I'm not allowed to do:

```
System.out.print((char)(letter + i) + " ");
```

Comment: It sounds like the challenge wants you to make a class with a custom `toString`.

Comment: What is the line you can't modify? The `System.out.print` into the loop?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the original assignment/challenge you have to solve. That way we can see what you are supposed to do and what additional information are available.

Answer (score 1):

IMO pointless, but doeable taks **as requested**.

*code ordered by  creation timestamp DESC, so "newest" on top*

*Hell, yet even shorter version*

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String letter="";
  for (char  i= 'X'; i <='Z'; i++) {
      System.out.print(letter + i + " ");
  }
}
```

*Edited and added even shorter solution*

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String i="";
  for (char c = 'X'; c <='Z'; c++) {
      String letter = i + c; 
      System.out.print(letter + i + " ");
  }
}
```

*First version*

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String all="XYZ";
  String i="";
  for (char c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
      String letter = i+all.charAt(c); 
      System.out.print(letter + i + " ");
  }
}
```

Prints `X Y Z`,
with preserved
`System.out.print(letter + i + " ");`

*Bonus: This shortens the code even more, but violates "no mod rule"*

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String letter=" ";
  for (char  i= 'X'; i <='Z'; i++) {
      System.out.print(letter + i);
  }
}
```

Probably some other golfcode migician will come and do this even shorter as I am so bad at this.

*Trolololo lolloolollolloooo trollooloolooooo*

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  System.out.print("X Y Z");  
  String letter="";
  String i=letter;
  System.out.print(letter + i + " "); //Preserved!
}
```